# Exclude folder from WAR file in Netbeans 6+

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, packaging, netbeans6.8

I have I think simple problem, but somehow it's causing some trouble. 
I have WAR project in Netbeans, and the contents look like this:

- WEB-INF
- images
- lib
- src
- stylesheets

Now, folder 'src' contains some other folders with javascript code, that is minified during build process and placed in 'lib' directory.

Oviously as js is now minified and compressed 'src' folder and it's contents are no longer needed in WAR file, so I decided to exclude it from WAR file. I went to Properties->Build->Packaging and this is where my problem starts.

I can't figure out what mask should I use there to exclude 'src' and it's contents. Tried **/src/*.* but no luck.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used src/** and that seems to be effective.